# JVM crash when using JTable

Tags: java, crash, jtable, jvm

I have an industrial PC with an Intel Atom D2550 1.86 GHz CPU, its embedded graphics adapter and 4 Gb RAM running Windows 7 (32 bit) and when I run a Java program on this computer I get a **Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working** (Problem Event Name **BEX** and Fault Module Name **StackHash_2264**).

I have tried both Java8 and Java7 with the same results. I have tried with both just JRE installed, and with a full JDK installed on this machine.

The same Java applicaton works well on this PC if I use Ubuntu 14.10 instead.

A small Hello World application works well, and using a lot of trial and error I could determine that the error occurs when I use a **JTable** with content. Using a JTable without content is ok though.

This application works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And this application causes the JVM crash:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new String[][] { { "1", "2", "3" }, { "1", "2", "3" } }, new String[] {"A", "B", "C" })), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have Googled a lot on this issue without any success. The only tip I found was to disable DEP for the application causing the error, but Windows won't let me disable DEP for java.exe.

I have more crash dumps if it would help anyone, just let me know what you need.

Comment: First thing I would check is if there are any driver updates (especially graphics) available for the machine. if there are no up to date drivers from the machine vendor, check if updated intel drivers can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Durandal, but I have already downloaded the latest Intel drivers for the graphics adapter explicitly. I also tried a utility from Intel that looks for udated drivers on all Intel components, but it did not find anything.

Comment: You can try to disable hardware acceleration for Java2D using the system properties (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html), presumably -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false turns it off (rendering performance drops notably, but for desktop apps its bearable). If this doesn't help either, I have no clue what the problem may be.

Comment: Interesting tip, thanks @Durandal, exactly something like that I was looking for. Unfortunately it didn't help, I tried most of the switches proposed on that site.