# JTable causes my application to crash

Tags: java, swing, crash, jtable

I am creating a fairly simple application for a school project. It's a contact manager. I want to display all the contacts in a table, I never used JTables before and it's confusing the crap out of me. I have done lots of research, I only found one thread with the same problem as me but it had no answer or anything helpful.

[JVM crash when using JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844086/jvm-crash-when-using-jtable)

Here's my code to create a table. Just a heads up, I am not looking to create anything complicated. Just a table where I can insert and remove data. That's all.

```
String[] columnLabels = {"Name", "Number", "Email", "Address"};
Object[][] data = {{"test 1", "test 2"}, {"test 3", "test 4"}};

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnLabels);
```

If I just insert

```
JTable table = new JTable(10,4);
```

Then it will work just fine. Maybe someone can shed some light because I do not know what's wrong. Thanks <3

Here is what the console tells me btw:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You are attempting to setup a table w/four columns, but when you feed in the data for it, you are only giving it two columns per row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're model array contains 2 rows with 2 columns while your column names array contains 4 elements, hence 4 columns. That's the problem. Provide a data array with 4 elements per row (may be null) and it should work.

From the source of the constructor you're using:

```
 public int getRowCount() { return rowData.length; }
 public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
 public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return rowData[row][col]; }
```

As you can see the renderer looks at the length of `columnNames` for the number of columns (4 here) and iterates over that (so 0 - 3). Eventually it calls `getValueAt(0, 2)` and this in turn calls `rowData[0][2]` and - boom - the col index is out of bounds.

In contrast `JTable table = new JTable(10,4);` just creates a table with an empty model of 10 rows and 4 columns:

```
public JTable(int numRows, int numColumns) {
    this(new DefaultTableModel(numRows, numColumns));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I was about to give up and just use a JTextArea. But that wouldn't be "clean".